# wordpress-add codes to function.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i want to create my first theme. i added my codes in header.php and function.php but my theme doesn't know i added function.php to my theme at all!
here the codes in function.php:

```
<?php
    DEFINE("THEME_LOC",get_template_directory_uri() );
    remove_action('wp_head','wp_generator');
    function enq_style(){
        wp_register_style('style',THEME_LOC.'/style.css',array(),'1','all',false);
        wp_enqueue_style('style');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enq_style');
?>
```

when i call THEME_LOC from header.php. it doesn't know i stored my theme location into this constant.
what's the problem?
shall i include my function.php into my theme or something?
i've got another question too.
does style.css add to my theme automatically or i have to register that style to my theme like what i did in fucntion.php?

Comment: Wordpress will not automatically include your style.css file for you, you'll need to include it yourself. They way you did it looks like it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but even when i don't register my stylesheet (like that) and move it to a folder in my theme folder like "stylesheets". my theme will be removed from themes. i think every theme folder needs style.css to be shown  in theme list either i registered that style or not.

Comment: that's right. this method works for every stylesheet. either wordpress default style theme(style.css) or every style you want to add to your theme. thanks.

Comment: Yes, wordpress pulls the theme info from the comments at the top of the style.css file that needs to be in the theme root, but it doesn't include the css in the theme unless you tell it to. This way you can structure your theme files how ever you'd like. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

`define( "THEME_LOC", get_template_directory_uri() );`

Comment: It doesn't work. I echo it and it shows me just THEME_LOC string.

Comment: I have tested and its working fine. Can you please turn on debug mode and check it if any errors/warnings coming out?

Comment: thanks, it solved. the problem was in function.php name. i had to rename it to functions.php and it works fine now.

Comment: If it is helpful then can you please accept this as an answer? Thanks :-) @user3087607